# Lightning Out Event Handling

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events

I have an application which includes an Application event. There are 2 components. Component A has a form which when the button is clicked it fires and event. Component B has an aura:handler and receives the form values via the Event.  This all works ok when internal in SFDC and not using Lightning Out. However however when I use the same components within Lightning out Component B does not receive or process the event fired from Component A.

I noted in the following [Is there a way to handle a Lightning Event from a Visualforce Page using Lightning Out?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106513/is-there-a-way-to-handle-a-lightning-event-from-a-visualforce-page-using-lightni) tips which allowed me to check if firing the Event in Component A did fire. This does work ok however Component B does not read the event at all.  On reading https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_considerations.htm there are some restrictions on how events are handled in Lightning Out but I have not seen an example of what I can do to get around this. Does anyone have any tips on this. For Component B I need it to refresh, or pick up that an application event has fired from component A.

As you can tell I'm pretty new to this so searching around in the dark.

Thanks for any tips on this.

Comment: If you add code here and explain whats not working we are happy to help ?

Answer (score 1):

to resolve this I needed to create both components in the lightning out page and not just create the parent one and assume the second one would load from the Application.